# Open browser in older version of Java

Tags: java, browser

I am trying to open a URI in a browser from a Java application. I know that in the current version of Java this can be done by using java.awt.Desktop, but that class is not available in earlier versions of Java, such as 1.5, which is what I am using. Is there a way to open the default browser with a given URI in earlier versions of Java?

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do the trick

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BareBonesBrowserLaunch {

    private static final String errMsg = "Error attempting to launch web browser";

    public static void openURL(String url) {
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        try {
            if (osName.startsWith("Mac OS")) {
                Class fileMgr = Class.forName("com.apple.eio.FileManager");
                Method openURL = fileMgr.getDeclaredMethod("openURL", new Class[] {String.class});
                openURL.invoke(null, new Object[] {url});
            } else if (osName.startsWith("Windows")) {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
            } else { //assume Unix or Linux
                String[] browsers = { "firefox", "opera", "konqueror", "epiphany", "mozilla", "netscape" };
                String browser = null;
                for (int count = 0; count < browsers.length && browser == null; count++) {
                    if (Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"which", browsers[count]}).waitFor() == 0) {
                        browser = browsers[count];
                    }
                }
                if (browser == null) {
                    throw new Exception("Could not find web browser");
                } else {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {browser, url});
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errMsg + ":\n" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. For a rich client GUI launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), use the [BasicService.showDocument(URL)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL%29) method.  Here is a small [demo. of the BasicService](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#bs).
2. For non-web-start apps., use [BrowserLauncher2](http://browserlaunch2.sourceforge.net/):

   > ..a library that facilitates opening a browser from a Java application and directing the browser to a supplied url. In most cases the browser opened will be the user's default browser.